# approximation of the sum

Tags: approximation, summation

I have difficulties to find an approximation formula  (or bound from the below) for the following sum:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\left( \frac{1}{35}\right)^{k-1}(n-k)!\left(k-\frac 32\right)!.
$$

Comment: @David: Could you throw light on what you mean by $\left( k - \frac32\right)!$?

Comment: @Sivaram The close connection with [the preceding question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94337/approximation-formula-for-the-integral) should give a strong hint :-).

Comment: I've use representation of $\beta$ function in terms of $\Gamma$ function. Now I got the following sum and I have no idea how to approximate it. $\Gamma(k-0.5)=(k-3/2)!$